# tns run ios --bundle Fails clang-4.0: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: ios, macos, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Get this Error 
'clang-4.0: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files'

each time I run `tns run ios --bundle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-installed Xcode then

```
conda deactivate
```

works for me. Just ran that on the terminal then reinstall for new project and for old ones remove the platforms and add them back

Answer (score 0):

Try to run by using this command:- **tns run iOS --bundle --device deviceName**

Otherwise open terminal and type this command:-

```
sudo update-alternatives --install \
/usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/bin/clang++ 100

sudo update-alternatives --install \
/usr/bin/clang clang /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/bin/clang 100
```

After running those two commands, the build was able to continue.

Comment: still the same error 
`` clang-4.0: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files``